# How to get files listed within specific time range

Tags: bash, filtering, file-listing

How can I list files within specific time range:

1. Files those modification date isn't greater than 5 hours.
2. Files that fall into period like 10-th of December through 20-th of December.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find /YOUR/SEARCH/DIR -type f -mmin -300 2> /dev/null
```

Finds every file for your first criteria.

For the second:

```
touch -d "2011-12-10" 2012-12-10
touch -d "2011-12-21" 2012-12-21
find /YOUR/SEARCH/DIR -type f -anewer 2012-12-10 ! -anewer 2012-12-21 2> /dev/null
```

It first creates two reference files based on your date criterias, then search by using them.

Answer (score 0):

The find command an option, -newerXY, which simplifies the problem:

```
$ find . -name "*.html" -newermt "13-Sep-2023 1:49" ! -newermt "13-sep-2023 1:49:21.75" | wc -l
52
$ find . -name "*.html" -newermt "13-Sep-2023 1:49" ! -newermt "2023-09-13T01:49:23" | wc -l
64
```

There may be other acceptable time formats.  The man page is not clear about that.